# Informatica call workflow twice with different param files - only last one taken for both

Tags: parameter-passing, workflow, informatica

I am trying to call workflow 'child' twice in sequence from workflow 'mother', using batch command pmcmd -paramfile, with two different parameter files.

So essentially, workflow 'mother' consists of two program tasks in sequence, each of them calling a child workflow, with its own paramater file.

command task 1:

```
pmcmd startworkflow -sv $PMCMD_INTSERVICE -d $PMCMD_DOMAIN -uv PMCMD_USER -pv PMCMD_PSWD -f CDWH -paramfile $PMRootDir/BWParam/parfile1.parm -wait wf_generic
```

command task 2:

```
pmcmd startworkflow -sv $PMCMD_INTSERVICE -d $PMCMD_DOMAIN -uv PMCMD_USER -pv PMCMD_PSWD -f CDWH -paramfile $PMRootDir/BWParam/parfile2.parm -wait wf_generic
```

However, the behaviour that we are seeing is that both 'child' workflows are started with parfile2.parm (obtained from log info).

If I update the filename in the last pmcmd command, the parameter file is updated for both.

Is there any way to fix this?

thanks

PS informatica workflow manager 9.6.1 hf3.

Comment: Are you using two command tasks in your 'mother' workflow? How do they look like exactly? Please post the commands. Are you using parameters for the parameter filename too?

Comment: A screenshot of the workflow would be useful. Are we taking about two command tasks or one task with two commands? What's the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I found is to keep just using the same param file, but to update the variable needed in a preceding command step:

```
sed -i 's/WF_INTERFACE=.*/WF_INTERFACE=NXN2WDWH_QSCRAD_/' $PMRootDir/BWParam/global_params.parm
```

edit:
frustratingly, it stopped working somehow - only the value placed in the second task is used for both, I have no idea why.